# How to set break point on one file of a project which has many files with same name?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, ambiguity

I want to set a break point in gdb on file service.cpp on line 45 and I do:

```
gdb> break service.cpp:45
```

The problem is that there are many service.cpp files in my application and it is not picking the one I am interested in.  How can I specify the right service.cpp file?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Specify the full path:

```
gdb> break /Full/path/to/service.cpp:45
```

Comment: If I set a function name, like `service.cpp:main` for some reason it finds the wrong one even with a full path (it finds the service.cpp thats located in the project root directory), not sure why this is happening

Comment: @SSH This You have multiple main functions?

Comment: Sorry this was about 5 years ago, I can't remember :(

Comment: Does not work for me on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Error message: `"No source file named /Full/path/to/service.cpp"` even if `!ls -l /Full/path/to/service.cpp` works fine on the gdb prompt.

Comment: @Tobias - maybe try a windows path? Might depend on what view of the filesystem your debugger has in that context. There is probably a way to turn on some more logging, too? I'm not a gdb expert on that side of things though.

Comment: By full path, do you mean, A) the full path from /, B), the path from the binary to the source file, C) the path from the current working directory to the source file, D) the path from where the gdb command was ran to the source file, E) something else? I tried A and D but it didn't seem to work, it always said the source file didn't exist.

Comment: Just FYI, I think the issue I ran into is a bug in GDB 9.1

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Carl 's answer,
In case anyone gets `No source file named /Full/path/to/service.c` like @Tobias,
make sure to add the debugging `-g` flag to main and the source file you want to access, like `main.c` and `foo.c`.

Then make sure `main` uses the `-g` compiled `operable` file, wich might mean you'd have to update and relink a library, for instance.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the Q and doesn't answer anything, Hypothetical issues are not an SO thing ;)

Comment: I wanted to properly comment this solution to the same problem someone else had on the main answers'  thread but lacked the minimal reputation, so I just added as another answer. My mistake was trying to access manually linked libraries (compiled without `-g`)  on gdb and I got the same "No source file named /Full/path/to/foo.cpp" error as reported above, it was just a matter of recompiling w gdb flag and relinking files. But I couldn't comment that without 50 rep

Answer (score 1):

Just give same trailing components that differs the file from others :

filename:linenum
Specifies the line linenum in the source file filename. If filename is a relative file name, then it will match any source file name with the same trailing components. For example, if filename is `gcc/expr.c', then it will match source file name of /build/trunk/gcc/expr.c, but not /build/trunk/libcpp/expr.c or /build/trunk/gcc/x-expr.c.

https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Specify-Location.html

Comment: The accepted answer is much more clear and you basically saying the same, just more complicated and with more words.

Comment: No. The accepted answer gives full path solution. What I wrote is relative path solution.